# How to use Redis correctly?

Tags: redis

My problem:

I have 10000 coupon code for our users. Each user will get one at most. For **performance** reason, I choose Redis and use a HashMap for the results: key is `userId`, value is the `couponCode`. When a user takes one code, the userId-code pair will be saved into the hashmap. Also the data pair should be saved into a SQL db.

How to design the system, so that when Redis crashes, data will not be lost?

Comment: this hashmap where is this?

Answer (score 1):

> How to design the system, so that when Redis crashes, data will not be
>   lost?

I would start by investigating the RDB and AOF persistence models and decide what level of data-safety is appropriate for your use-case.

[Redis Persistence](https://redis.io/topics/persistence#ok-so-what-should-i-use)

Information on how Redis handles Sigterm.

[Redis Signals Handling](https://redis.io/topics/signals#handling-of-sigterm)

**Note:**

Assuming you are running a master / slave setup.  I would note that Redis uses asynchronous replication, meaning it is not possible to ensure the slave actually received a given write, so there is always a window for data loss. 
[Redis Replication Docs](https://redis.io/topics/replication)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

How about saving them to the database first, and "refreshing" the hash map at the end?